# Logstash http output with user password

Tags: http, logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

I am receiving log data from TCP and sending it to a https url as json using logstash.

Here is my configuration

> ```
> input {
>         tcp {
>                 port => 8443
>                 codec => json_lines { charset => CP1252 }
>                 }
> }
> output {
> http
> {
>         format=>"json"
>         http_method=>"post"
>         url=>"https://alert.com/ts/dmd/evcon"
>         headers => ["username","password"]
> }
> }
> ```

and im receiving the below error:

```
[HTTP Output Failure] Could not fetch URL {:url=>"https://alert.com/ts/dmd/evcon", :headers=>{"username","password", "Content-Type"=>"application/json"}, :message=>"PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target", :class=>"Manticore::ClientProtocolException", :backtrace=>["/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/manticore-0.6.4-java/lib/manticore/response.rb:37:in `block in initialize'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/manticore-0.6.4-java/lib/manticore/response.rb:79:in `call'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-output-http-5.2.4/lib/logstash/outputs/http.rb:239:in `send_event'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-output-http-5.2.4/lib/logstash/outputs/http.rb:175:in `send_events'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-output-http-5.2.4/lib/logstash/outputs/http.rb:124:in `multi_receive'", "org/logstash/config/ir/compiler/OutputStrategyExt.java:118:in `multi_receive'", "org/logstash/config/ir/compiler/AbstractOutputDelegatorExt.java:101:in `multi_receive'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:239:in `block in start_workers'"], :will_retry=>true}
```

Im not sure if headers is the place to give the username and password of the url.
Also, added the below for avoiding the cert error:

```
        ssl_certificate_validation => false
        verify_ssl => false
```

which gave me

```
[2020-05-07T04:48:03,430][ERROR][logstash.outputs.http    ] Unknown setting 'verify_ssl' for http
[2020-05-07T04:48:03,435][ERROR][logstash.outputs.http    ] Unknown setting 'ssl_certificate_validation' for http
```

How do i use http output here?

Comment: Which version of logstash are you running?

Comment: @apt-get_install_skill Logstash 7.2